# What is the algorithm used in FindInstance?

Tags: findinstance

Is FindInstance guaranteed to find an instance if one exists? Conversely, if it does not find an instance, does that mean an instance does not exist at all? Finally, is there a way to change the Method Automatic option and if so what are the alternatives?

Comment: I do not know the exact internals but: Quite certainly, more than one single algorithm is used and there are no guarantees that an instance can be found even if there exists one.